# I can't get sessionid when use vue-cookies

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to get `sessionid` from cookie by vue-cookies.

So I import vue-cookies, and print the cookies

```
import VueCookies from 'vue-cookies';
Vue.use(VueCookies);
console.log(Vue.cookies.keys());
```

The result displays only `["csrftoken"]` after I logged in, but in Chrome application-->Storage-->Cookies, there are two keys: `csrftoken` and `sessionid`.

Could you tell me why I can not get `sessionid` in `Vue.cookies.keys()`?
 Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Django session's default head httponly is True,after I set it to False,The problem is solved

django setting.py

```
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
```